# Renpy python variable text color

Tags: python, renpy

I started making a novel and learn renpy really recently, and I came across a difficulty that I couldn't find the solution. I put an input for the user to define the name of the protagonist, but when I declare the character, the color that I designated to appear in the text box is not working.

Here a piece of my code:

```
python:
    sn = ""

define luca =   Character("     Luca Kaneshiro", color="#ffffff")
define sn =     Character("%(sn)s", color="#ffffff")

label start:
    call askname

    luca "Hey %(sn)s."
    sn "Hi, Luca!"

label askname:
    $ sn = renpy.input("What's my name?", length=32)
```

here's how the text in displayed

[image]

I was expecting it to be displayed in white color, but instead it was displayed in yellow, the collor that I defined for gui.accent_color. Is there any solution for that? A way to turn the text in the sn variable into a normal text or something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Renpy's documentation](https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/dialogue.html) on `Character`, you need to attached a `who_style` arguments, specifically `who_color` in this case:

```py
define sn = Character("%(sn)s", who_color="#ffffff")
```

Also, unrelated but renpy doc [uses](https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/text.html) square bracket for string/text interpolation instead, so in case the above doesn't work, try the following:

```py
define sn = Character("[sn]", who_color="#ffffff")
```